# Stacking XHTML elements using z-index

Tags: javascript, css, xhtml, z-index, onmouseover

Three `div` tags with `p` tags within, stacked one on top of the other. I need them to come forward onmouseover by modifying the `z-index` property. Could you please tell me why this isn't working?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<!-- Lab Program 8A // Element stacking -->

<head>
    <title>Lab 8A : Changing element stacking on mouseover</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function MoveUp(here)
        {
            here.style.zIndex= 5;
        }
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        div {position:absolute}
        p {font-size:100px; margin:0px; border:solid}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <p style="background-color:green" onmouseover="this.style.zIndex=5">IWT Lab 1</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p style="background-color:yellow; margin-left:50px" onmouseover="MoveUp(this)">IWT Lab 2</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p  style="background-color:pink;  margin-left:100px" onmouseover="MoveUp(this)">IWT Lab 3</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**New Code :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<!-- Lab Program 8A // Element stacking -->
<head>
<title>Lab 8A : Changing element stacking on mouseover</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function MoveUp(here)
{
here.style.zIndex= 1 ;
}
function MoveDown(here)
{
here.style.zIndex = 0 ;
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
div {position:absolute}
p {position:absolute; font-size:100px; margin:0px; border:solid; height:150px; width:500px}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div onmouseover="MoveUp(this)" onmouseout="MoveDown(this)">
<p style="background-color:green">IWT Lab 1</p>
</div>
<div onmouseover="MoveUp(this)" onmouseout="MoveDown(this)">
<p style="background-color:yellow; margin-left:50px" onmouseover="MoveUp(this)">IWT Lab 2</p>
</div>
<div onmouseover="MoveUp(this)" onmouseout="MoveDown(this)">
<p  style="background-color:pink;  margin-left:100px">IWT Lab 3</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't doing this with CSS `:hover` pseudo class instead of Javascript?

Comment: i moved the onmouseover event to the div tag and and also added the onmouseout event. the code works flawlessly now. thanks a lot.

Comment: @DavidT this is a college lab program. its supposed to be done this way. :hover would be way simpler but this is to demonstrate/teach us mouse events.

Comment: fair enough, least you got it working now.

Answer (score 0):

`z-index` only applies to *positioned* elements. While your `div` elements as `position: absolute`, your `p` elements (which you are setting the `z-index` on) are `position: static` (the default).

Elements are *positioned* if their `position` property has any valid value other than `static`.

It looks like you should move your `onmouseover` event handlers to the div elements.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you aren't reducing the z-index back to the default once the mouse leaves - add in a function `onmouseout` that resets the z-index to 0 or 1 or something.